# Cannot log in to Firefox account due to "NetworkError"

Tags: networking, 18.04, login, firefox, sync

Noticed that my Sync hasn't been working for many days.

I logged out and noticed that I cannot log in to Firefox account/sync on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. It doesn't even ask my password, just aborts and says there's "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resources":

[image: Network error]

However, **there's not a real network error** as I'm posting this with the **same machine and same Firefox** :p

Comment: Are network working ? Can you connect to any website ?

Comment: Did you even read my question fully? I posted this with the same machine and same Firefox so obviously the network is working, right?

Comment: I missed that, sorry. But please be polite when you reply ...